# ¿Cómo funciona el controlador de Spring?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

El caso, es que estoy intentando aprender Spring por mi cuenta, pero no encuentro un buen tutorial. Estoy hecho un lio porque yo tenia entendido, que el controlador de Spring era `.xml` al estilo [struts2](/questions/tagged/struts2), pero en cambio cuando creo el proyecto en [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse) y le doy a `Spring mvc project`, me crea una clase llamada `HomeController.java` que hace las veces de controlador, ¿Y entonces dónde esta el `xml` en cuestión?

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el Dispatcher con los Controller. La pregunta es muy amplia, pero creo que puedes encontrar bastantes tutoriales en español sobre spring, como por ejemplo https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/aplicaciones-web-con-spring-boot-capa-a-capa/

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a echarle un vistazo

Comment: no hay algún otro tutorial donde no usen Maven?  es que no he usado nunca Maven y me lía todavía mas.

Comment: Hoy día es complicado encontrar un proyecto donde no se use Maven o Gradle, pero sólo se usan para montar el proyecto, puedes simplemente obviar esa parte

Comment: hay un tutorial bastante completo con pildoras informaticas, el explica desde lo basico que es descargando las librerias de spring y importandolas a un proyecto y despues explica porque es mejor maven que es como hoy en día se realiza.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo buscar información sobre spring boot. La mayoría de las configuraciones vienen listas desde que creas  tu proyecto con la ayuda de [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/). Ahora ya no son necesarias las anotaciones `xml`. Todo se hace con clases java y anotaciones. Con `@SpringBootApplication` la mayoría de las configuraciones se llevan a cabo y no es necesario configurar un *dispatcher controller*. Por ejemplo, con [thymeleaf](/questions/tagged/thymeleaf) solo basta agregarlo en el *initializr* y spring detectará automáticamente las configuraciones para que el dispatcher reconozca la extensión `*.html`.

También es posible trabajar con [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) y es muy sencillo hacer el cambio. Solo hay que seleccionarlo dentro de las opciones del inicializador. Todas las dependencias trabajan de la misma manera en Gradle y [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).

El *controller* tiene esta estructura:

```
@Controller
public class usuarioController(){

   @PostMapping("/url/{valor}")
   public String metodo(Objeto ObjectoMapedado, Map<String, Object> model){
       /// .... Tus operaciones
       return "nombreDeLaVista";
   }

}
```

Para resolver con thymeleaf y html solo se requiere esta dependencia en maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Las anotaciones de [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) configuraran todo automáticamente, eso incluye los beans, los controllers y las configuraciones extras que quieras. Ya no es necesario `xml`.

---

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

Te puedes descargar el proyecto desde [aqui](https://www.plustransfer.com/download.php?id=2c4ec288c4650d3feda58fc71390a4d9).

Lo hice con Gradle. Se puede hacer también con Maven. Es un proyecto ya funcional con un servidor [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) embebido. Esto quiere decir que puedes generar un jar y correrlo en cualquier PC con java 1.8 y tendrás tu servidor local funcionando. Entre las dependencias tambien agregue una BD de datos [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) y [jpa](/questions/tagged/jpa).

- `H2` es una BD de datos embebida así que no ocupas incluir otra más. (Pequeños proyectos y pruebas)
- `JPA` incluye hibernate para el `CRUD` que necesitas.

Revisa el proyecto.No requiere ningúna configuración en `XML`!! `:D`.

Esta bastante intuitivo. El problema viene con JPA y hibernate pero solo es cuestión de acostumbrarse un poco.

Te recomiendo algún curso de UDEMY. Hay buenos cursos en español que te ayudaran bastante.

En resumen. Spring Boot facilita mucho las configuraciones de manera que te centras más en el código que en el XML.

> Despues subo el proyecto a gitHub.

Comment: Spring boot? pues mirare a ver pero me as dejado mas perdido de lo que estaba.     Por faavor algun videotutorial que valga la pena? llevo desde la semana pasada intentando hacer un dynamic web page con spring y no hay manera, no entiendo nada en ningun lado

Comment: No he usado nunca Spring, empiezo ahora y no estoy entendiendo nada, y me ha pedido que haga un CRUD.

Comment: @sergipc88 En realidad es muy fácil. Te voy a actualizar un poco la pregunta.

Comment: pues muchas gracias voy a echarle un vistazo

Answer (score 1):

Aqui un [tutorial de Spring](http://www.jtech.ua.es/j2ee/publico/spring-2012-13/wholesite.pdf).

Tienes varios ficheros de configuracion `xml`, tu puedes definir todos los controladores que quieras con la anotacion `@Controller`, estos reciben las peticiones a una URL definida. Lo normal es crear una clase `Controller` por cada funcionalidad distinta que tengas en la vista, también puedes definir varios métodos dentro de un *controller* que reciben urls diferentes.

Comment: vale muchas gracias, una dudila spring es compatible con hibernate no?